# Import CSV get ADUser from E-Mail and include blank line for no results

Tags: powershell

So I'm having a little trouble, I have a large CSV file with e-mail addresses where I'm trying to search AD for the relevant user information.

Some of the e-mails in this CSV don't have a matching AD object (eg. noreply@xy.com) but I need to keep them in this file, I also want the relevant AD data on the correct line.

Right now my script is getting all the information I want, but it is also getting rid of the blank lines when no user info is found, any thoughts?

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\myfile.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-Aduser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$(
$_.SenderAddress)'" -Properties *} | Select SamAccountName, Name, Company
```

Comment: Put a null validation inside foreach loop with if. Store the import in a variable. Run foreach and see that the inside variable is null or not. If not null do the above operation else append the email Id directly

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. I added email address that you are sending in for the search to the result as a place holder for the missing.

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\myfile.csv" | % { if($ad = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.SenderAddress)'" -Properties EmailAddress, Company){$ad}else{New-Object PSObject -Property @{"EmailAddress" = $($_.Email); "SamAccountname" = $Null; "Company"=$Null}} } | Select EmailAddress, SamAccountName, Name, Company
```